# Automate generation of SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, server, ssl-certificate

How could I automate the generation of SSL certificates for different subdomains? In my workflow, different subdomains `ab.mydomain.com`, `cd.mydomain.com`, `ab.mynewdomain.com`, etc. will point to the IP of my Nginx machine.

I want to generate SSL certificates for these subdomains configured on my Nginx. How could I automate the generation of SSL certificates? Is there a way? Is there any library that can do this for me? I can also start with free SSL certificates, that will not be a problem.

I tried to search this, but could not find any answer.

Comment: _IF this is public_ you probably want [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) which uses LetsEncrypt (which is free and supports both multiple certs and up to 100 hostnames per cert, but does limit frequency of _changes_) and _can_ automatically handle the SSL/TLS-related configuration of ngninx for you (among other things). But this isn't really a programming or development question.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Is there a way to automate certificate generation, where I could pass the answers to the questions as arguments?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Is there a way to automate certificate generation, where I could pass the answers to the questions as arguments?

Comment: If you mean certbot, it has _many_ commandline options; see under 'get help / documentation' [the user guide](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html) (much like a traditional man page except with the syntax at the end instead of the beginning). If that's not enough, it's open source which you can read and if you want change -- and specific points of code or change probably _are_ ontopic for SO.